# Windows 7 can't make back up

Tags: windows-7, backup

I've been trying to get Windows 7 to make a backup for a week or so. I'm backing up to a local NAS and I'm getting this error:

> Windows Backup: Troubleshooting Options
>
> Check your backup
>
> Windows Backup could not create a zip file. This could be because the drive that Windows is installed on does not have enough space or it could be a temporary error. Make sure you have at least 400 MB of free space and try again.
>
> Backup time: 2009-09-07 14:48
>   Backup location: \VANGELIS\Shared\Backup\lennon\
>   Error code: 0x81000015

My local hard disk has 290GB free and my NAS has 200GB free. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: How long before the error appears?  Is it immediate?  I assume you can  connect to \\VANGELIS\Shared\Backup\lennon\ and write okay?  Can you adjust your backup just to back up a few files as a test and see if it still errors?

Comment: I can connect. It takes a couple of hours, sometimes more, to reach the error. The first time it took like 16hs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is what it claims to be : your hard disk space ran out **in the process** of creating the zip file.

290GB free is useless if you have a 1TB hard disk, and you are backing up 600+ GB of files. What happens with Windows Backup is that it will attempt to create the zip file on your local hard disk first - if you have 600GB file of files you might need 400GB (or more even). So, while 7 happily zips up your files, totally oblivious that as the backup zip file gets bigger and bigger, it eats into the existing free space, and will eventually run into the problem where there is simply not enough space anymore to *finish* zipping up the file.

Solution : Move some data off the local hard disk - if you are going to use Windows 7 backup, I recommend you have more than 40% disk space free (more will be better, of course).

Post your total hard disk configuration here : in short 290GB free out of ??? GB? Then we will be able to confirm whether will 7 backup work for you.

Comment: My disk is 500GB, 290GB free, so I'm only using 210GB and backing up way less than that..

Answer (score 1):

If you have Carbonite backup installed disable it during the backup or schedule it to be disabled during your scheduled backup.

Answer (score 0):

This [MS TechNet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/5bd7cbc9-2689-4a48-a50b-ba256229ef19), suggests a couple of potential causes...

1. Your anti-virus or compression program is interfering with the backup process
2. You are dual booting Windows 7 using BootMagic or some other boot manager

If 1:
Try unassociating your compression program with Zip files and turning off your anti-virus while running the backup.

If 2.
You might need to set up Windows to use its internal boot manager.

Comment: I'm not dual booting, but I do have 7zip installed.

Comment: Ok, removing 7zip didn't help.